# Maven : Reference maven.runtime.classpath not found

Tags: maven, ant, pom.xml, maven-plugin, build.xml

I have two files : build.xml and pom.xml.

I executed "run-java-file" task from build.xml using command "ant -f build.xml run-java-file", but got following error in java.

> /root/Documents/RELEASE_786_BRANCH/build.xml:36: Reference
>   maven.runtime.classpath not found.

code block from build.xml :

```
<target name="run-java-file">
    <java fork="true" classname="com.mysoftware.setup.install.SetNewDatabase" classpathref="maven.runtime.classpath" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="really" />
    </java>
</target>
```

code block from pom.xml :

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
             <execution>
                  <configuration>
                      <target>
                           <ant target="run-java-file" antfile="/root/Documents/RELEASE_786_BRANCH/build.xml">
                               <property name="skip.maven.ant.tasks" value="true" />
                               <reference torefid="maven.runtime.classpath" refid="maven.runtime.classpath"/>
                            </ant>
                       </target>
                  </configuration>
            </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

EDIT :

I have found that executing "mvn install" will compile all .java files to target/classes folder, available in .class format. So I tried executing them, but got following error.

```
java -cp /root/Documents/RELEASE_786_BRANCH/target/classes
com.mysoftware.setup.install.SetNewDatabase
```

ERROR:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.apache.log4j.LogManager
>           at com.mysoftware.setup.install.SetNewDatabase.(SetNewDatabase.java:46)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.log4j.LogManager
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:591)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:952)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:897)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:880)
>           ... 1 more

Is there any classpath problem, if YES, please suggest what is to be set as -cp?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think your `build.xml` is meant to be called directly.

Comment: @JFMeier, then pls suggest a sutable method

Comment: On first glance it looks like you need to call Maven, and Maven will call the antrun plugin. So install Maven (if you haven't already) and call something like `mvn clean verify`.

Comment: @JFMeier have tried that, but it did not invoke tasks from build.xml

Comment: @AnshuPatel Of course it does not cause Maven will not use `build.xml´ only if you use `maven-antrun-plugin`. The question is why you use maven-ant-run instead of maven directory...

Comment: So you're executing an Ant script, that executes a Maven pom, which has an embedded Ant task, that executes an Ant script (which apparently contains maven-ant-tasks, which you tell the script to skip). I honestly don't even know where to begin. I suggest choosing *one* of these technologies and reading its Getting Started page.